# UI5: get path for new object in model

Tags: sapui5

I often have some kind of master-detail situation where i try to use a single model for both master and detail view.

The detail page is bound directly to an element in the list with `.bindElement(path)` when you select an item in the list. The path is available from the binding context. Everyone is happy:

```
//click handler for list item:
var context = this.getBindingContext();
oDetailPage.bindElement(context.getPath());
oApp.toDetail(oDetailPage);
```

The challenge is when the list page has an "add" button. I create a new object and put that into the model. But how do I find the path? i have no context:

```
//click handler for "add" button
var newStuff = {
  propA: "foo",
  propB: 13
};
oModel.setData(oModel.getData().concat(newStuff));
oDetailPage.bindElement(/* What??? */);
oApp.toDetail(oDetailPage);
```

I've searched for a `.findPath(newStuff)` method but no such thing exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi, unfortunatly I am unable to test this but I think this should work**

The binding path is pretty much pointer to a specific entry in a collection. The path value does depend on a couple of variables, such as how your model is structured.

For example, if the Model data looks like this :

```
{"results" : [
            {propA: "foo",
             propB: 13
            },
            {propA: "ber",
             propB: 14
            }]
```

}

And you concat

```
{propA: "newItem",
 propB: 15
}
```

I believe you binding path would be

```
"/results/2"
```

You can also, find the most recent index with something like

```
this.getModel("yourModel").getObject("results").length;
```

Edit -
Unless I miss understand your quesitons, your new entry should be at the end of the model.

Comment: I have also observed that the numeric paths match the index in the underlying array, but have not found any verification of this in the docs. If this is indeed something I can count on, then great :) that's a viable solution

Comment: I think the path in your example would be `"/results/2"`though, since they are zero-based

Answer (score 1):

here are 2 cases

```
//click handler for "add" button
var newStuff = {
  propA: "foo",
  propB: 13
};

// case 1: root of model data is an array
var oData = oModel.getProperty("/");
oData.push(newStuff);
oDetailPage.bindElement("/" + oData.length - 1);

// case 2: we appends to /results
var oData = oModel.getProperty("/results");
oData.push(newStuff);
oDetailPage.bindElement("/results/" + oData.length - 1);
```